# Detemine if a word is an email address

Tags: java

The professor has asked us to do this:

> Your program will receive an email address in args[0]. You must determine if it could be a real email address. This means:
>
> There must be an '@' character in it.
> There must be at least one character before the '@' character.
> After the '@' character, there must be a '.' character.
> There must be at least one character between the '@' character and the '.' character.
> There must be at least one character following the '.' character.

I have no idea where to even start. I set up the string value of args[0]but I don't know what to do. We learned about multiple if else statements and boolean stuff in class I think he wants us to use those. Like for example how would I go about saying "The email must contain @" like how do I code for that?

Comment: Have you learned about Regexs?

Comment: First step: Learn to [Regular Expression](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Why are Javascript and Java both included as tags? They're COMPLETELY different....

Answer (score -1):

As others have said, the "real" answer is to use Regular Expressions, but if you haven't covered them in class yet, I doubt the professor expects you to use them. There are several functions in Javascript (which I assume you're using, and not Java) that help with parsing strings:

1. `indexOf()` will tell you if one string is contained in another string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf
2. `split()` will help you figure out what's on either side of the `@` symbol.
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
3. `length` will tell you how many characters are in a string.
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

That should give you a solid start.

Comment: Well, looks like maybe you *are* using Java. Java has those functions, too, but you'll have to look up how exactly to use them.